# Nasm Greatest common divisor

Tags: assembly, nasm, greatest-common-divisor

I want to write a program where you enter two numbers and get the Greatest common divisor 
with the following pseudo code:

```
Euclid(a, b)
while (b != 0)
{
r = a mod b
a = b
b = r
}
return a
```

THis is my current version which gives me an error:52:invalid combination of opcode and operands.

```
%include "asm_io.inc"

segment .data
prompt1 db    "Enter a number: ", 0       
prompt2 db    "Enter another number: ", 0

segment .bss
input1  resd 1
input2  resd 1

segment .text
    global  asm_main
asm_main:
    enter   0,0               ; setup routine
    pusha

    mov     eax, prompt1      
    call    print_string
    call    read_int   
    push eax       

    mov     eax, prompt2       
    call    print_string
    call    read_int    
    push eax      


    call euclid

    call print_int



    popa
    mov     eax, 0            ; return back to C
    leave                     
    ret


    ; Function euclid

    euclid:
         push ebp
         mov ebp, esp

         mov ebx, [ebp+8]
         mov ecx, [ebp+12]



         _while: 
            div ecx,ebx
            mov ebx,ecx
            mov ecx,edx
            cmp ecx,0
            jz _end
            jmp _while
         _end: 
            mov eax,ebx

        pop ebp
        ret
```

I am totally new to assembly and nasm and i hope you can help me to find the error or false syntax.

Comment: Post the relevant code in the question itself. Also, which part of the assembly are you having problems with?

Comment: well i guess its the while loop here and maybe the stack

Comment: You'll need to be more specific. What's wrong with the stack? You push 2 items and later put them into registers fine. If you're comparing against `0`, then you'll want something to decrement towards `0`. I can't see a `DEC` anywhere in the `_while`. :)

Comment: well i though that ecx gets 0 at some point while running the loop

Comment: My asm is a little rusty, but it looks like your `euclid` routine computes the answer, puts it in `eax`, then when it returns, the calling routine clobbers the answer with `popa` before it's used or saved anywhere.

Comment: gcd.asm:30:error:parser:instruction expected. Can't find the error there.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `div ecx,ebx` instruction. If you want to perform `ecx`/`ebx` then you must use the `div r/m32` form that divides the 64 bit quantity formed from `edx` and `eax` by the given operand. As such, you'll have to take care to zero out `edx` for a 32 bit dividend (or use the sign-extending `cdq` instruction for signed operations).
Code could look like:

```
xor edx, edx
mov eax, ecx
div ebx  ; eax = ecx / ebx, remainder in edx
```

When in doubt, use the [instruction set reference](http://www.intel.com/products/processor/manuals/).

There may be logic errors in your code, I only answered the question you asked.

Answer (score 0):

The error in your code is your logic. You should return 'r' and not 'a', and in 'while loop' you should compare the value of 'a mod b' with zero and not of 'b' with zero. Also there are more cases that occur due to comparison of two integer,like, first integer can be smaller or greater than the second one.You should consider those comparisons too,in your algorithm. I dont know nasm or assembly at all but you should try this psudo code below. The 'min(a,b)' is a function that you should write that returns the minimum of 'a' and 'b'.I dont know the syntax of nasm or assembly but the logic should work well.All the best!

```
 Euclid(a,b)

       if(min(a,b)==a){
             while (b mod a != 0) { 
                r = b mod a
                b = a
                a = r
             }
             return r
          }

        else{
               while(a mod b!=0){
                  r = a mod b
                  a = b
                  b = r
              }
               return r
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a program to calculate the greatest common divisor using inline assembly.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int gcd( int a, int b ) {
    int result ;
    /* Compute Greatest Common Divisor using Euclid's Algorithm */
    __asm__ __volatile__ ( "movl %1, %%eax;"
                          "movl %2, %%ebx;"
                          "CONTD: cmpl $0, %%ebx;"
                          "je DONE;"
                          "xorl %%edx, %%edx;"
                          "idivl %%ebx;"
                          "movl %%ebx, %%eax;"
                          "movl %%edx, %%ebx;"
                          "jmp CONTD;"
                          "DONE: movl %%eax, %0;" : "=g" (result) : "g" (a), "g" (b)
                          );

    return result ;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    printf("%d \n", gcd(30, 50));
    return 0;
}
```

Here is where I found it, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15971/Using-Inline-Assembly-in-C-C